# FileNotFoundError/The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: python

line 1307

```
        # Start the process
        try:
            hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                                     # no special security
                                     None, None,
                                     int(not close_fds),
                                     creationflags,
                                     env,
                                     cwd,
                                     startupinfo)
```

```
  File "C:\Users\asus\anaconda3\lib\subprocess.py", line 1307, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,

FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] Sistem belirtilen dosyayı bulamıyor
```

```
input_string = input("Enter the input string :")
f_name=input("enter the name of video")
frame_extraction(f_name)
call(["ffmpeg", "-i",f_name, "-q:a", "0", "-map", "a", "tmp/audio.mp3", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)

encode_string(input_string)
call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "tmp/%d.png" , "-vcodec", "png", "tmp/video.mov", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)

call(["ffmpeg", "-i", "tmp/video.mov", "-i", "tmp/audio.mp3", "-codec", "copy", "video.mov", "-y"],stdout=open(os.devnull, "w"), stderr=STDOUT)
clean_tmp()
```

Comment: You have to add your code also!

Comment: Edit the post with your code.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you need to uninstall ffmpeg from python

> pip uninstall ffmpeg-python

Then install in conda env

> conda install -c conda-forge ffmpeg